# How to specify arguments for substitute in mapcar?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

For example, I have a list of "strings" : ("First" "second" "third.").
And I need to replace all "s" to "a" -> (("Firat")...etc
I've found very beautiful function called substitute, but it works only for one sequence.
Can I use substitute in mapcar ? Something like this:

```
(mapcar 'substitute #\d #\o '(("test") ("wow") ("waow")))
```

Comment: Don't use mapcar here, a loop seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can wrap a `LAMBDA` around the function:

```
(mapcar (lambda (string) (substitute #\d #\o string)) '("test" "wow" "waow"))
;=> ("test" "wdw" "wadw")
```

Or you can use a helper function called `CURRY` (which is not part of the Common Lisp standard, but is available in [Alexandria](https://common-lisp.net/project/alexandria/) for example).

```
(ql:quickload :alexandria)
(use-package :alexandria)
(mapcar (curry #'substitute #\d #\o) '("test" "wow" "waow"))
;=> ("test" "wdw" "wadw")
```

For multiple strings in sublists, you can use nested mapcar/lambda:

```
(mapcar (lambda (sentence) 
          (mapcar (lambda (string) 
                    (substitute #\d #\o string))
                  sentence))
        '(("I" "like" "my" "dog.") ("My" "dog" "likes" "me" "too.")))
;=> (("I" "like" "my" "ddg.") ("My" "ddg" "likes" "me" "tdd."))
```

The inner `LAMBDA` could be changed to a `CURRY` too:

```
(mapcar (lambda (sentence) 
          (mapcar (curry #'substitute #\d #\o) sentence))
        '(("I" "like" "my" "dog.") ("My" "dog" "likes" "me" "too.")))
```

Or even:

```
(mapcar (curry #'mapcar (curry #'substitute #\d #\o))
        '(("I" "like" "my" "dog.") ("My" "dog" "likes" "me" "too.")))
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! 
What it does: uses Lambda (string) to each element in list, right?

Comment: Lambda makes an anonymous function, which the mapcar then applies to each element. The function takes a single argument and uses substitute on it.

Comment: Hm, okay. So that's the main idea of using Lambda inside of mapcar? Mapcar only needs functions with 1 arguments (which is going to be their list), and if we declare anonymous function it can loop through our list ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. `CURRY` also does the same thing; it's just a bit shorter to write.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
But what if we changed the way sentences are described?
Each sentence — separate list. For example:
(("I" "like" "my" "dog.") ("My" "dog" "likes" "me" "too."))
We need to add additional lambda to handle that?
Something like:
(mapcar (lambda (ls)((lambda (string) (substitute #\d #\o string)))) '(("I" "like" "cats."))) ?

Comment: You can use `MAPCAR` inside the anonymous function too. I'll add an example.

Comment: Wow, it is freakin' genious. Really much appreciated. Gonna research more about functionals and using lambda. Thanks again!

Comment: It might be time to consider recursion: I'll add an answer with some code,

Answer (score 3):

I'm adding to jkiiski's very nice answer one final possibility to specify arguments to `substitute` in this case, though it's probably not what you need:

```lisp
(mapcar #'substitute '(#\x #\x #\x) '(#\a #\b #\c) '("abcd" "abcd" "abcd"))
;; => ("xbcd" "axcd" "abxd")
```

Here for every `i` up to the lowest length of any passed list, `mapcar` passes the `i`th element of the first list as first argument, the `i`th element of the second as second argument and the `i` th element as third argument to `substitute`. This works because [`mapcar`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm) takes one or any number of lists.

Using this only makes sense if you want to perform different substitutions on (almost) each of the strings.

Answer (score 2):

Beyond a flat list one could consider recursion, to handle the general nesting case:

```
(labels ((my-sub (s)
           (typecase s
             (string (substitute #\d #\o s))
             (list (mapcar #'my-sub s))
             (otherwise s))))
  (my-sub '(("I" "like" "my" "dog.")
        ("My" ("dog" "likes" "me") "too."))))
```